# Доступ к коллекции с данными

Tags: android

База данных находится в текстовом файле (их может быть несколько).
Создаю в файле `Database.java` коллекцию:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map;

public class Database {
    Map<String, Person> person = new HashMap<String, Person>();
}

class Person {
        String surname;
        String name;
        String patronymic;
    char sex;
}
```

Из главной активности `StartActivity.java` запускаю активность `FilesActivity.java` для чтения и парсинга текстового файла базы данных и записываю в коллекцию:

```
Database db = new Database();

...

db.person.put(id, new Person(...));

...
```

Коллекция создана, но прочитать её я могу только из активность `FilesActivity.java`.
Подскажите, как правильную архитектуру, чтобы доступ к полученным данным был из любой активности моего приложения?
З.Ы. Не форматируется код, поправьте, пжл.

Comment: @falstaf, а как сделать с ипользованием  "DI с сингл-скоупом"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если править архитектуру, то используй `sqlite`, а по вопросу используй силингтон

Comment: Мне не нужно сохранять данные в sqlite, а возвращать их в текстовый файл.
А синглтоном я намучился и ничего путного не получил. Если можно, дайте код.

Comment: код сейчас дать увы не получиться, - вынеси коллекцию в отдельный класс, коллекция созданная в activity и не должна быть видна из других activity, при переходе на другую activity ваша уничтожается.
как вариант можно при старте считывать данные из файла в базу работать  с базой а при выходе экспортировать данные обратно в файл и очистить базу, немного криво но попутно решаются многие проблемы

Comment: Коллекция находится в отдельном классе. Не пойму, как её объявлять там?

Comment: попробуй его сделать public static, только поосторожнее с многопоточностью и другими радостями жизни

Comment: В классе Database объявил:

public static Database db = new Database();

В ативности пишу в коллекцию:

Database.db.person.put(id, new Person(...));

Так работает, но не нарушаю святцы?

Comment: Если проект учебный то лучше все же разобраться с силингтоном, если заказ то работает ? ну и не трогай, допиливай и здавай ))

Comment: Пишу для собственного удовольствия. За решение - спасибо!

Comment: Оставим в покое тот факт, что синглтоны вообще — это плохо. Но, в любом случае, не используйте синглтоны на android, никогда.

Comment: встречал неплохие библиотеки для android с использованием силингтона(название сейчас не припомню, использовалась для кэширования картинок), можно аргументировать столь категоричное высказывание? ( с тем что используя силингтон можно наломать дров не спорю, но безоговорочно говорить что он плох тоже не  стану)

Comment: Учитывая, что instance синглтона может быть прибит андроидом, это может привести к интересным side-effects. А вообще, имхо, наличие синглтона — признак плохой или непродуманной архитектуры. Ну или налепленных впоследствии костылей. А если же возникла такая необходимость, то всё это отлично заменяется DI с сингл-скоупом.

Comment: @falstaf Меня конечно закидают камнями. но я делал что-то вроде синглтона (только экземпляр хранился в моем классе унаследованном от Application). А так да, синглтон это не круто :)